# Preload with limit rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can one preload an association with a limit in Rails?

For example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end
```

This works fine:

```
Post.all.preload(:comments)
```

But how I can preload only **one** COMMENT for each POST. (Ideally one RANDOM COMMENT for each POST)

Something like this:

```
Post.all.preload(:comments.limit(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create custom associations below, with order as random and limit just 1 
note: if you using mysql change RANDOM() to RAND()

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
 has_one  :random_comment, -> { order("RANDOM()").limit(1) }, class_name: "Comment"
end
```

then you can do

```
Post.all.preload(:random_comment)
```

Comment: Don't forget to access it through `post.random_comment`. If you'll call `post.comments` it will still result in a 1+N query.

Comment: You should drop the `.limit(1)` since having a `has_one` association already establishes that.

Comment: I use *has_one  :random_comment, class_name: "Comment"*
but I have

Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:16

  Comment Load (96.9ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["post_id", 53], ["post_id", 54], ["post_id", 55], ["post_id", 56], ["post_id", 57], ["post_id", 58], ["post_id", 59]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:16

in the same like ** Post.all.preload(:comments)**  but we show only one comment

Comment: @SerhiiDanovskyi ^ Pop quiz. What SQL-query would you use to fetch one comment of every post in one single query? (Assuming you already have the posts.)

Comment: I've given you some time to think. The reason Rails requests all comments (for each post) is because the query is pretty hard to generate. From the retrieved records only the first for each post is instantiated. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group